# Running Cython in Jupyter iPython

Tags: python, anaconda, cython, jupyter-notebook

Running an iterative loop for a geometric progression for a time trial, using the Cython interface.

Get an error on compile (shift-enter): CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
%load_ext Cython
```

> 

```
%%cython
def geo_prog_cython(double alpha, int n):
    cdef double current = 1.0
    cdef double sum = current
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        current = current * alpha
        sum = sum + current
    return sum
```

The error:

```
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py in build_extension(self, ext)
    530                                          debug=self.debug,
    531                                          extra_postargs=extra_args,
--> 532                                          depends=ext.depends)
    533 
    534         # XXX outdated variable, kept here in case third-part code
```

Comment: There is no error visible. Paste the whole error report.

Comment: DistutilsExecError                        
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py in _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, verbose, dry_run)
    158                           "command %r failed with exit status %d"
--> 159                           % (cmd, exit_status))
    160             elif os.WIFSTOPPED(status):

DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Can you please paste the *whole* traceback,. not just the error.

Comment: have you tried using cython outside of jupyter?  I think this may just be an issue with your cython configuration

Comment: Any hint as to what is the _right_ Cython setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is quite old but I thought this may help some others.

I ran into this issue on Windows for an old Py2.7 project.

If on Windows, and using Py2.7 check that you have the MS Visual Studio C++ compiler for Python installed ([download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266)). Not sure what changes are necessary for Py3.

For your anaconda environment, locate the `Lib\distutils` directory and create a `distutils.cfg` file (if not already there, otherwise just modify the current file as necessary).

You want the build config to look like below.

`[build]

compiler=msvc`

If on linux, make sure you have the necessary `devel` packages available, e.g.

Ubuntu: `apt-get install python-devel`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to reproduce this without error using Anaconda3:

```
%load_ext Cython
%%cython -a

def geo_prog_cython(double alpha, int n):
    cdef double current = 1.0
    cdef double sum = current
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        current = current * alpha
        sum = sum + current
    return sum
```

Example:

```
geo_prog_cython(0.5, 5)
1.96875
```

The code seems fine. It must be an issue with your set up.